# CreateSwapChainForHwnd with DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH : erroneous stretch

Tags: winapi, directx, direct2d

I'm using a SwapChain created with CreateSwapChainForHwnd with DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH scaling. When the sizes of the swapchain and the window client area differ, the SwapChain's associated bitmap is correctly scaled, but its origin is moved as if the window borders were accounted in the stretch process although there sizes are constant.

Is there a way to fix or circumvent this issue ?
Thank you for the help !

*(More precisely : for a client area larger that swapchain, the origin of the bitmap in shifted down, right proportionally respectively to title-bar height and left border width, the part of the bitmap thus moved outside the client area being invisible; a reverse shift is produced with client area smaller than swapchain).*

---

Below a minimal code to reproduce this issue based on visual studio desktop app template. I put everything in InitInstance() (I know it's bad), appart from classical DX #includes and declarations. It corresponds to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts except I create the swapchain with CreateSwapChainForHwnd() instead of CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow() :

---

## The pb appears fror MDI childs, as well as for SDI windows with a menu. The way the buffer bitmap is drawn, CopyFromMemory, DrawBitmap or even D2D drawing doesn't matter, as shown in images with the two diagonals made with DrawLine().226707-stretchedout.png
Actually the white bands are flickering during resizing.

Example, starting from Visual Studios's destop app template, replace InitInstance() below and add D2D includes and declarations...

...

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
ATOM aMainClass;
ATOM aChildClass;
const TCHAR lpszMainClassName[] = TEXT("FCLAYERMAIN");
const TCHAR lpszChildClassName[] = TEXT("FCLAYERCHILD");

hInst = hInstance;
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);

//prepare MDI windows (main + MDI client + one child)
WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style = 0;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon = NULL;
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_APPWORKSPACE + 1);
wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName = lpszMainClassName;
wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
aMainClass = RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

wcex.lpfnWndProc = ChildWndProc;
wcex.lpszClassName = lpszChildClassName;
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
aChildClass = RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

hWndMDI = CreateWindow((LPCTSTR)aMainClass,
szTitle,
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
CW_USEDEFAULT,
0,
CW_USEDEFAULT,
0,
NULL,
NULL,
hInst,
NULL);

CLIENTCREATESTRUCT ccs;
ccs.idFirstChild = 5000;
hwndClient = CreateWindow(TEXT("mdiclient"),
NULL,
WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CHILD | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | MDIS_ALLCHILDSTYLES,
0,
0,
0,
0,
hWndMDI,
0,
hInst,
(LPSTR)&ccs);
ShowWindow(hWndMDI, SW_SHOW);
ShowWindow(hwndClient, SW_SHOW);

//so as the initial child's client are fits the D2D swapchain (256*256px)
RECT Rect;
Rect.left = 0;
Rect.top = 0;
Rect.right = 256;
Rect.bottom = 256;
AdjustWindowRect(&Rect,
WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU| WS_SIZEBOX, FALSE);

HWND hWnd = CreateMDIWindow(
(LPCTSTR)aChildClass,
szTitle,
WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU| WS_SIZEBOX,
CW_USEDEFAULT,
CW_USEDEFAULT,
Rect.right - Rect.left,
Rect.bottom - Rect.top,
hwndClient,
hInst,
NULL);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

//create D2D + D3D + DXGI machinery
D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS debugOptions;
debugOptions.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_NONE;
HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(
D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
__uuidof(ID2D1Factory1),
&debugOptions,
(void*)&m_D2DFactory
);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
{
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
};
hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
nullptr,
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
0,
creationFlags,
featureLevels,
ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
&m_pD3D11device,
NULL,
NULL
);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
IDXGIDevice1 dxgiDevice;
hr = m_pD3D11device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void*)&dxgiDevice);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
hr = m_D2DFactory->CreateDevice(
dxgiDevice,
&m_d2dDevice
);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
m_d2dDevice->CreateDeviceContext(
D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE,
&m_d2dContext
);
}
}
IDXGIAdapter dxgiAdapter;
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
hr = dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&dxgiAdapter);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
hr = dxgiAdapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_dxgiFactory));
SafeRelease(&dxgiAdapter);
dxgiDevice->SetMaximumFrameLatency(1);
SafeRelease(&dxgiDevice);
}
}
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = { 0 };
swapChainDesc.Width = 256;
swapChainDesc.Height = 256;
swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDesc.Stereo = FALSE;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH; //DXGI_SCALING_ASPECT_RATIO_STRETCH seems not supported
swapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE;
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
hr = m_dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
m_pD3D11device,
hWnd,
&swapChainDesc,
nullptr,
nullptr,
&(m_swapChain)
);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
hr = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_dxgiBackBuffer));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 bitmapProperties = D2D1::BitmapProperties1(
D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW,
D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
0,
0,
NULL
);
/
//just in case dpi=0 doesn't work:
bitmapProperties.dpiX = GetDpiForWindow(hWnd);
bitmapProperties.dpiY = GetDpiForWindow(hWnd);
/
hr = m_d2dContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(
m_dxgiBackBuffer,
&bitmapProperties,
&(m_pBitmap)
);
}
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
D2D1_SIZE_U bitmapSize = m_pBitmap->GetPixelSize();
m_d2dContext->BeginDraw();
m_d2dContext->SetTarget(m_pBitmap);
ID2D1SolidColorBrush* m_pBlackBrush;
hr = m_d2dContext->CreateSolidColorBrush(
D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Red, 1.0f),
&m_pBlackBrush
);
m_d2dContext->DrawLine(
D2D1::Point2F(0.0f, 0.0f),
D2D1::Point2F(bitmapSize.height, bitmapSize.width),
m_pBlackBrush,
2.0f,
NULL);
m_d2dContext->DrawLine(
D2D1::Point2F(0.0f, bitmapSize.width),
D2D1::Point2F(bitmapSize.height, 0.0f),
m_pBlackBrush,
2.0f,
NULL);
}
hr = m_d2dContext->EndDraw();
hr = m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
{
int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
// Analyse les sélections de menu :
switch (wmId)
{
case IDM_ABOUT:
DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
break;
case IDM_EXIT:
DestroyWindow(hWnd);
break;
default:
return DefFrameProc(hWnd, hwndClient, message, wParam, lParam);
}
}
break;
case WM_DESTROY:
PostQuitMessage(0);
break;
default:
return DefFrameProc(hWnd, hwndClient, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ChildWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
return DefMDIChildProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

...

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Does it work correctly if your window has no border (i.e. `WS_POPUP`)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Below a minimal code based on visual stdio desktop app template. I put everything in InitInstance(), appart from classical DX #includes and declarations. It corresponds to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts except I create the swapchain with CreateSwapChainForHwnd() instead of CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(). How can I share the code and result images ?

Comment: The code and image is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/948490/createswapchainforhwnd-with-dxgi-scaling-stretch-e.html?childToView=950223#answer-950223

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `AdjustWindowRect` with `AdjustWindowRectEx` and specify `WS_EX_MDICHILD` extended window style.

Another thing, you’re rendering and even presenting some graphics from within `InitInstance` method. That’s not the right time for that, too early. Instead, you should move rendering into `WM_PAINT` handler of the window for which you have created the swap chain.

P.S. [This sample](https://github.com/Const-me/Direct2D-demo) might help.

Comment: Thank you ! You are right, AdjustWindowRectEx with WS_EX_MDICHILD must be used for the initial fit of swapchain and client area size. However, the DXGI scaling problem remains on re-sizing. I suppose it is an undocumented issue with Direct2D or DXGI. For the second remark, of course the sample I provided was just the minimal easily reproducible demo, it is not intended as a model of app !!!

Comment: @Fab-cea Can you confirm you can still reproduce the issue when rendering and presenting from WM_PAINT handler?

Comment: Yes. The moment the buffer bitmap is drawn through CopyFromMemory, DrawBitmap or even D2D drawing doesn't matter. The scaling issue with DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH remains, at least for MDI child windows and plain windows with a visible menu bar. (@dialer) No problem with borderless windows.

Comment: @Fab-cea Do you handle `WM_SIZE` for your innermost window you’re rendering into, call IDXGISwapChain.ResizeBuffers in the handler, and getting `S_OK` code from that call?

Comment: @Fab-cea Another thing you should check – run Spy++ (Tools / Spy++ in visual studio), verify the size of your MDI child window. It should say it has 256x256 pixels client rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

The streching error only occurs for windows with borders and/or menu bar. A possible workaround is thus to add a borderless child window (hWndPic) to the MDI child (hWnd) itself:

```
//initialization :

   hWnd = CreateMDIWindow(
       (LPCTSTR)aChildClass,
       szTitle,
       WS_SIZEBOX|WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU ,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,
       Rect.right - Rect.left,
       Rect.bottom - Rect.top,
       hwndClient,
       hInst,
       NULL);

   hWndPic = CreateWindow(
       (LPCTSTR)aPicClass,
       NULL,
       WS_CHILD,
       0,
       0,
       256,
       256,
       hWnd,
       0,
       hInst,
       NULL);
```

Then resize this picture window in response to WM_SIZE sent to the MDI child hWnd; that's all! then there is no need to repaint the picture when the window is resized and the stretch process is correctly handled by D2D, benefitting from hardware acceleration.

```
// windows procedures :

LRESULT CALLBACK ChildWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        RECT Rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd,&Rect);
        SetWindowPos(
            hWndPic,
            HWND_TOP,
            0,
            0,
            Rect.right - Rect.left,
            Rect.bottom - Rect.top,
            0
        );
    }

    }
    return DefMDIChildProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK PicWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```